# Angular - Submit Grouped Form as Single Form Without Groups

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am building a reactive form in Angular, and I want to split up my form into multiple components.

I have a component for `Itinerary`, `Customer Information`, `Checkout Information`, and `Additional Information`. All of these components have the same entire form that will be submitted once all component screens are completed, but each component needs to be checked for validity before moving to the next screen.

For example, let's say my entire form is created with FormBuilder:

```
// Itinerary
arrivalDate: [new Date()],
arrivalTime: ['12:00'],
arrivalLocation: [''],
returnDate: [new Date()],
returnTime: ['12:00'],
  
// Customer Information
customerName: [null],
customerAddress: [null],
customerCity: [null],
customerState: [null],
customerZip: [null],

// Checkout information
billingCity: [null],
billingAddress1: [null],
billingState: [null],
billingZip: [null],

// Additional Info

notes: [''],
emailAddress: [null],
promoDescription: [null],
referralSource: [null],
```

All of these fields would be required.

One thought is to split up the form into multiple groups, like so:

```
this.fb.group({
  itinerary: this.fb.group({ ... })
  customerInfo: this.fb.group({...}_
  ...
})
```

This way, I can check for validity of each "group" as a [FormGroup] inside the individual component. If I am in the `itinerary` component, once the form group is valid, I can move to the next page.

The problem is that now my form value is submitted as a large form with nested groups rather than one big form like this:

```
myForm.value :
{
  itinerary: { 
    // itinerary form controls here
  },
  customerInfo: { 
    // customerInfo form controls here
  },
  checkoutInfo: { 
    // checkoutInfo form controls here
  },
  additionalInfo: { 
    // additionalInfo form controls here
  }
}
```

I need to submit everything as one entire form when the user is done going through all the pages, and cannot submit as a form with nested groups.

Is there a way in Angular to break a form up into different groups, while keeping the form in its original "full" value?

Comment: When you say 'submit the form' what exactly do you mean? Why can't you submit the nested form group? If it is an API limitation you could map the form values into a new object.

Comment: It is an API limitation, that's right. I can't submit the form with nested groups, it needs to be all one full json form value, not split into multiple groups... yes, I should map that. Can't believe I didn't think about that. Thank you

Comment: If you Use Material Components, the stepper control might be for you. You can separate fb.groups for each section and validate the form before moving to the next. In your submit you can merge all the forms into your JSON model and fire off to your API.   https://material.angular.io/components/stepper/overview

Comment: Thanks! I am not using Material, but rather PrimeNG which has a very similar functionality. I'm not sure why I didn't recognize the idea of merging these back together, or using map to begin with and making its own object. By any means, if you want to post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept so you can get the reputation from it